# How to block specified IP address programmatically in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to block the IP address for a specified range. I have written the code in the web.config file as:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  <security>
    <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false"></ipSecurity>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Which will block everything.

But when I run this code nothing getting blocked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25338177/2395663

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to take a look at the answer to the following question, maybe it can help you:

*"I doubt you can do that at the web.config level unless the "IP and Domain Restrictions" role is installed on the server itself."*

[Web.config 500 block ipaddress - Internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019887/web-config-500-block-ipaddress-internal-server-error)

Even if you're not getting the 500 error, maybe you just have to add the:

```
<clear/>
```

to remove all upstream restrictions? Let me know.

EDIT: added instructions to **configure Restriction access to websites using IP address in IIS 7**.

Here's a good link, explaining how to install "IP and Domains restrictions" in IIS 7, as this feature is not installed by default. If you don't install this feature, restrictions won't work!

http://linuxwebservertips.in/restrict-access-to-website-using-ip-address-in-iis-7/

Follow this guide and everything will work fine, As you can see, you can add multiple range restrictions too.

Comment: I have tried like this also <location path="resources">
  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
   <security>
    <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
        <clear/>
      </ipSecurity>
   </security>
  </system.webServer>
 </location>     This is the url i am getting when i execute the page http://localhost:1256/ipblocking12/test.aspx will this code work for localhost

Comment: It's useless to give a localhost URL, it's working only in your local server. To allow requests from your local machine you must write: `<add ipAddress="127.0.0.1" allowed="true" />`

Comment: i dont want to allow i need to block if i use the above code also the page is getting executed.I need to block that page

Comment: If you use `<ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">`, only listed IPs will have access.

Comment: i dont want to allow any ip.I want to block all the ips can you please let me know what are the changes i need to do in the code

Comment: If you have IIS 7, the module to block IPs is not installed by default. Follow these instructions to make it available: [IP-Address-block-IIS7](http://linuxwebservertips.in/restrict-access-to-website-using-ip-address-in-iis-7/). Let me know if it works.

Comment: this will block only one ip address but my actual requirement is i need to block ip addresses of a specified range(multiple ranges not single range)  i have used the code like this in web.config  <add ipAddress="83.116.119.0" subnetMask="255.255.255.0"/> but this also is not working

Answer (score 0):

This might help. I use it on a site where I don't have access to IIS. It works successfully in blocking individual IP addresses. It probably could be modified to block ranges.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnIPAddressBlockingHttpModuleForASPNETIn9Minutes.aspx